# How can I reduce space between elements in a fieldset

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to recude the space between the label and elements in a fieldset and failing miserably. In the attached grab I have provided, I would like to recude the spacing between each new element and around the fieldset. For the life of me I cannot seem to find a way to do it. It displays fine with normal spacing in FF bit un IE8, it seems to be doubling the spacing. I would be gratful if someone could show me a way to achieve this. Thanks

HTML

```
         <fieldset>
            <legend class="fld_company icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Select Company</legend>
                <div class="formMessage">Click again to open</div>
                    <div class="fld_fld">
                     <dl>
                      <dt>
                         <label for="BA_customer">Select a Company:</label>
                      </dt>
                      <dd>
                         <select name="BA_customer" id="BA_customer">
                           <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
                            <?php
                                do {  
                                ?>
                           <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
                            <?php
                                   } 
                                   while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
                                   $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);
                                   if($rows > 0)
                                   {
                                   mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
                                   $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
                                   }
                             ?>
                         </select>
                     </dd>
                    </dl>

            <!--- displays the address and dept from the change function -->

                <div id="BA_dept"></div>
                <div id="BA_address"></div>
          </fieldset>
```

CSS

```
legend
        {


        background:#00C621;
        color:#fff;
        font:17px/21px Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding:0 10px;
        margin:-26px 0 -2px -8px;
        font-weight:bold;
        border:1px solid #f2f2e6;
        border-color:#e5e5c3 #e5e5c3 #666661 #e5e5c3;
        cursor: pointer;

        }



legend.fld_company
        {

        width: 140px;

        }

fieldset.action
        {

        background:#9da2a6;
        border-color:#e5e5e5 #797c80 #797c80 #e5e5e5;
        margin-top:40px;

        }

fieldset
        {

        background:#f2f2e6;
        border:1px solid #e5e5e5;
        border-color:#e5e5e5 #e5e5e5 #666661 #e5e5e5;
        margin:10px 0 36px 0;
        width:490px;
        display:block;
        text-height:10px;
        }
```

[image: Reduce space between elements]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements are rendered differently in different browsers due to their browser default styles, but the form elements are the most inconsistent from the point of view of cross-browser compatibility. You should first reset the default browser style of your form elements and other related elements. Mostly margins and paddings of the elements to zero. e.g.

```
form, fieldset, legend, label, input{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Then re-style each elements individually in your way.

You also need to reset the outline and margin and padding of your dl and dd. Try this..

Answer (score 1):

It might be the `DT` and `DD` tags that have spacing. Try setting an `outline` around them to see, and then set the `margin` and/or `padding` to `0px`.